# In a profile text, I want to add a regex, that makes sure users input atleat 50 characters

Tags: regex

I want users to be able to enter a profile text, with spaces ( I have added space) but also allows commas and dots.
 Now if a user has a comma in the text, it gets an error.

I have used this:

```
 /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{50,}+$/
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: Still curious about the reason of the possessive quantifier.

Comment: @Loamhoof: Usually, in the version without possessive quantifier, the regex engine may optimize by not doing backtracking when it encounters an invalid character. I think adding the possessive quantifier is probably to make sure no backtracking is ever done, regardless of the implementation of the engine.

Comment: @nhahtdh I know what possessive quantifiers are. But there's only term in his expression so basically, no backtracking is possible in any case.

Comment: @Loamhoof: A naive implementation will backtrack when it encounters an invalid character, in each step walking back, it will try to match `$`, which it fails, until it reaches empty string and fail.

Comment: @nhahtdh Such an implementation would be primary, wouldn't it? Possessive quantifier aren't a basic tool, I'd find it queer to have a flawed implementation with advanced tools. But you may be right. An example would be welcome though :) (I'd know not to use regex with it then.)

Comment: @Loamhoof: I don't think it is flawed implementation (just that it is a slow implementation). I haven't looked at the source code of any implementation, but I think there should be some optimization there. What I stated above is the most basic and simple model that seems to replicate the result from the engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,.]{50,}$/
```

Adding `,` and `.` allows , and . as well. \s allows space.
`{50,}` makes sure that the input is at least 50 characters.

Comment: You need to escape the . as that will be a wildcard otherwise so \.

Comment: I believe there is no need to escape `.` when it is in `[]`.
So the code would work fine

Comment: @Shawn no you don't in a character class. Also, \s also allows \r\n\t as well. Even if it's easier to read, should be avoided (as it's not the required behavior).

Comment: @Loamhoof I'm not sure about that one? Do you have a reference source? My experience is \s is space and \t is tab and so on...

Comment: @Shawn [Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) of both critics :)

Comment: Well I learned something new, but then the question is would you want to count a carriage return or tab against your limit of 50? I would think not. So I think my answer works. :-)

Comment: @Shawn He may not want those characters at all :p but hey, he'll decide anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the following regex:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9\s,.]+){50,}$/
```

Explained: Allow ONE OR MORE letters (capital AND lowercase), numbers (0-9), commmas, periods of AT LEAST 50 characters long

I replaced the space with \s so its clearer to see your space also edited to allow a dot.

Comment: Along with this, it also doesn't allow a dot.

Comment: Wouldn't it be {0,50} so they enter 0 chars up to 50?

Comment: Oops read the question wrong sorry! yes {50,} I thought he said up to 50 chars.

Comment: You have to remove the parenthesis and the `+`.

Comment: Yes I think this does the trick. I also had to add æøå, and ended up with this: /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s,.æøå]+){50,}$/ - Thanks alot

Comment: I had to change it into /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s,.æøå]{50,}+)$/ for it to work. +) is moved after minimum 50. But anyway thanks alot for all your help.